# I got a 27.5" fork for my 26" bike, what size wheel should I run?

Tags: wheels

I have an Ellsworth AM bike that's running a 26" rear wheel. I just scored a great deal on an x-fusion sweep fork that's 160mm travel (same as the frame) but for a 27.5 wheel.

I am in search of a new wheel for it, and I wasn't sure if I would be better off running 26" wheels all around, or if I would be better off running a 27.5" wheel up front with a 26" wheel in the back.

Just looking for some advice before I bite the bullet on a new wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a different offset and a different fork height now, so whatever you do, you have already messed with the geo noticeably.

Borrow a 27.5 and a 26 front wheel from a friend for a day, go ride, figure out which one feels better. I would guess 26 would feel closer to how it used to but it should still handle differently due to the different offset, but who knows you might prefer the 27.5 even though that should leave your geo even more altered :)

Comment: I'd argue about noticeably changing the geometry. It depends what fork he was running before and what travel range the frame supports. 27.5 wheel on 27.5 fork would add like a couple of centimeters to the axle to crown. This can be offset by decreasing fork travel, which it probably supports.

Comment: Whoops, I meant the 26 would be closer to how it used to feel, was tired when I wrote it and messed it up. Edited now.

Comment: Why not 24" to compensate the change in fork length?

Comment: Aside from other factors which I can't be bothered to discuss, quickly visualizing it in my mind, makes me believe a 24 would leave the front end noticeably lower than before with 26wheel/26fork. That would have more negatives than being a fraction higher, when considering the kind of riding you are doing on a 160mm bike.