# Is it worth swapping MTB front forks/wheel to ISO 584/27.5" from ISO559/26"?

Tags: wheels, giant

Is there going to be some roll over benefit? how about getting up to speed?

I'd be using it at mount stromlo in Australia, everything except the black downhill...

EDIT: I am specifically talking about the rim size, assuming that there would be the same tire width/depth. So therefore a larger rolling circumference on the front than the back

Currently has a SRAM XO - 1 x 10 (11:32 cassette), front & rear brakes etc

Comment: Also, I edited in details to the title, so it's clear what sizes I think you're using. Note that there are four common sizes, plus the 36"/787 somewhat unusual one. So you really do need to be careful about what you buy - 26"/559, 27.5"/584, 700c or 29"/622 and 27"/630 (I think the latter is rare in MTB) [Wiggle has MTB tyres in all of those plus 650b/571](http://www.wiggle.com.au/cycle/tyres/27-630-wheel-size/?o=8)

Comment: You could put any size rim on the existing fork that fits.  As long as the disk rotor is a good fit, and the tyre doesn't end up larger than the frame spacing allows.   However I fail to see any significant advantage in a fork swap - you'll be nose-up compared to the original geometry, which will bugger up your climbing.  If you want an excuse to replace your bike, just buy.   A decent aftermarket fork will cost a good percentage of a new bike by itself, that's the way the parts market works.  And you end up with a whole bike to sell off later, to fund the new one.

Comment: ...and do bother to use the search functionality on SE.  Possible duplicate of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36767/i-got-a-27-5-fork-for-my-26-bike-what-size-wheel-should-i-run but its from the other side.

Comment: I did see that thread, but there wasn't really any definative answer other than 'You have changed the geometry', I'd really like to understand the riding implications of that change.

Comment: @Criggie My other bike is a Giant Glory so I am thinking of doing this more as an experiment rather than as a replacement, thanks for the input regarding the climbs :)

Comment: Okay - wheels are really easy to swap, so find/borrow a bigger front and put it on.  Be aware your front travel will be reduced, so avoid bottoming out the suspension.   Ride the bike a bit and compare, then swap back to your proper wheel.  See how you find it, and let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume I read this correctly that you want to replace the fork and wheel making the front a 27.5" and the rear will remain a 26"

If this is correct I don't think their would be any real benefit. There were several companies in the past that did similar things and don't any longer the 69er comes to mind which was a 26" in the back and a 29 in the front.

Rollover will improve for the front tire yes, but more than likely with the different geometry you will likely be putting more weight on the front wheel which will nullify any roll over gains. Also climbing will become significantly more challenging.

It will also track through corners differently. I would recommend sticking with the same size wheels. I don't think you will see an significant gains in doing so, or any gains for that matter. If anything I would recommend a fork of the same size with more travel if that's what your worried about. Your legs and body are the most important suspension though.